# javascript supplying argument value from different events

Tags: javascript

I have an ASP page that will compute all inputted values from 2 textboxes using ajax. I want to get the value on keyup:

```
    <input type="text" name="greetingScore" class="form-control" onkeyup="computeScore(this.value)">
<input type="text" name="closingScore" class="form-control" onkeyup="computeScore(this.value)">
```

and this is my javascript.

```
<script>
function computeScore(str,str2)
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (str.length==0)
      { 
      document.getElementById("pointsEarned").innerHTML="";
      return;
      }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("pointsEarned").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","computeScore.asp?a="+str"&b="+str2,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

What I want to know is how can I can distinguish the values that are inputted on the two textboxes.

Comment: If you attached handlers using `addEventListener` you would have known that from the event object.

Comment: If you just pass `this`, then you have the reference to the input element the event was triggered on. Btw., you function expects two parameters, but you’re passing only one – so your XMLHttpRequest will always send the value `undefined` for the GET parameter `b` …

Comment: I just solved my own problem. didnt know that onkeyup="computeScore(textbox1.value,this.value) is possible. Thanks anyways. :)